# apScrollTop plugin with jqm failing on page change

Tags: jquery-mobile

apScrollTop plugin gets messed up on jqm page change. I've tried to destroy it on page change, and reinit it after a few millis, no luck.

The git source shows a destroy call.. https://github.com/armin-pfaeffle/ap-scroll-top/blob/master/lib/js/ap-scroll-top.js

```
    $(document).on( "pagecontainerchange", function() {
        $.apScrollTop().destroy;
        setTimeout(function () {
            handleUp();
        },200);             
    });

function handleUp() {
        $.apScrollTop({
            'onInit': function(evt) {
                console.log('apScrollTop: init');
            }
        });

        // Add event listeners
        $.apScrollTop().on('apstInit', function(evt) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: init');
        });

        $.apScrollTop().on('apstToggle', function(evt, details) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: toggle / is visible: ' + details.visible);
        });

        $.apScrollTop().on('apstCssClassesUpdated', function(evt) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: cssClassesUpdated');
        });

        $.apScrollTop().on('apstPositionUpdated', function(evt) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: positionUpdated');
        });

        $.apScrollTop().on('apstEnabled', function(evt) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: enabled');
        });

        $.apScrollTop().on('apstDisabled', function(evt) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: disabled');
        });

        $.apScrollTop().on('apstBeforeScrollTo', function(evt, details) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: beforeScrollTo / position: ' + details.position + ', speed: ' + details.speed);

        });

        $.apScrollTop().on('apstScrolledTo', function(evt, details) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: scrolledTo / position: ' + details.position);
        });

        $.apScrollTop().on('apstDestroy', function(evt, details) {
            console.log('apScrollTop: destroy');
        });

}
```

Else some advice on a good jqm and page change compatible Scroll up thingie would be most welcome.

Comment: Try beforechange instead of pagecontainerchange -- check here. https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/ --  also you have  $(document).on( -- i think you need to use the page ID's eg --  $("#page1, #page2, #page3").on(

Comment: pagecontainerchange didn't help, i debugged it and it is triggering with document on, so no probs... i'm gonna go for another scroll plugin.

Comment: you can try iscroll == https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll